# SQLJDBCDriver -jaas.conf -kerberos

Tags: kerberos

I am working on Kerberos authentication and need help in jaas.conf file
I have below section in jaas.conf

```
  SQLJDBCDriver {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      principal =
      keyTab =
   }
```

I need one more SQLJDBCDriver section for another keytab and another principal
But when I add another section, the first and second both sections don't work.

Please help?

Comment: Add a semicolon `;` before the closing brace `}` (because each section may configure multiple modules, with semicolon as separator) and another semicolon after the closing brace (as separator betwen sections)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes semicolon is already present before and after the braces

Comment: SQLJDBCDriver {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      principal =
      keyTab ="";
   };SQLJDBCDriver {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      principal =
      keyTab =;
   };

Comment: Can we keep two SQLJDBCDriver sections?
When I keep any other section i.e "JassSample" it doesent work and when I keep "SQLJDBCDriver",  I get connected to DB.

please not that I am using JTDS driver for this connection

Comment: Duh... You may have different sections with different names, to reach different services. But you can't have duplicates. If necessary, define 2 conf files and set the proper one with `setProperty()` just before initiating the connection.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by setProperty(), I give .conf file reference in env.sh file?

Comment: No. In custom Java code. Or as `-D...=...` in an session-specific JAVA_OPTS env variable.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issue where I try to set up multiple principals to different db instances.

You can specify multiple sections/principals in jaas.conf,

```
SQLJDBCDriver_1 {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      principal =
      keyTab =
   }
SQLJDBCDriver_2 {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      principal =
      keyTab =
   }
```

With the latest SQL JDBC driver, you can specify section name, for example:

```
jdbc:sqldriver://...;jaasConfigurationName=SQLJDBCDriver_1;
```

I also documented the findings in https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/828